# Choose one random part of loop

Tags: python

```
a = 1
b = 2 

for i in range():
    print(a)
    #print(b)
```

I am trying to make a code. How can I make that randomly in one part of loop it will print b. For example one it will print "112111" and next time "211111".

Comment: Did you mean the loop should print `b` just once?

Answer (score 1):

From the context of your question you want to print b only once.

```
import random

a = 1
b = 2

import random
b_index = random.randint(0,3)

res = [ a if i != b_index else b for i in range(4) ]
print(res)
```

Comment: b_is_printed is not used

Comment: The code works though, I removed it. I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but this should work. You assign at which index should B be printed at random and run the loop as below:

```py
import random

A = 1
B = 2
LEN = 6
PRINT_B_INDEX = random.randint(0, LEN-1)

def main():
    for i in range(LEN):
        if i == PRINT_B_INDEX:
            print(B)
        else:
            print(A)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `random` module. One possible solution is `random.shuffle()`, which will shuffle the elements of `s`. This does not require a `for` loop.

```py
import random
s = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "2"]
random.shuffle(s)
print("".join(s))
```

Comment: And if I want to be sure that "2" will be printed only once?

Comment: Then you need to state that more explicitly in your question. Will update my solution.